# Data is not inserting in my database from my java program

Tags: java, database, swing, applet, awt

[image: My DataBase]

After my java Program run the form will come up after providing details in form it should put that data in my database but every time after providing data its only show #Deleted in all rows.
is there any problems with my insert Query or with database connectivity while during compiling and running java file it doesn't showed any type of error or warning.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Anpr extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
            ImageIcon icon; 
            ImageIcon img3;
            JLabel imglab3,label3,label4,label5,label6,label7,label8,label9,label10;
            Dimension dimension;
            JTextField pid,name,cno,age,bgrp,addr,anydis;
            JComboBox<String> gen; 
     Anpr(){    
                dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();      
                int x=(int)((dimension.getWidth() - 650)/2);
                int y=(int)((dimension.getHeight() - 650)/2);
                setLocation(x, y);
                setSize(600,600);
                setLayout(null);
                setUndecorated(true);
          //      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                icon = new ImageIcon("image/medical-record.png");
                setIconImage(icon.getImage());
                setTitle("Add New Patient Record");
                setResizable(false);
                label3 = new JLabel("Patient ID");
                label3.setBounds(150,50,80,30);
                label4 = new JLabel("Name");
                label4.setBounds(150,90,80,30);
                label5 = new JLabel("Contact No");
                label5.setBounds(150,130,80,30);
                label6 = new JLabel("Age");
                label6.setBounds(150,170,80,30);
                label7 = new JLabel("Gender");
                label7.setBounds(150,210,80,30);
                label8 = new JLabel("Blood Group");
                label8.setBounds(150,250,80,30);
                label9 = new JLabel("Address");
                label9.setBounds(150,290,80,30);
                label10 = new JLabel("Any Major Disease Suffered Earlier");
                label10.setBounds(150,330,200,30);
                add(label3);
                add(label4);
                add(label5);
                add(label6);
                add(label7);
                add(label8);
                add(label9);
                add(label10);
                JButton btnsa=new JButton("Save");
                JButton btnco=new JButton("Close");
                btnsa.setBounds(150,450,80,30);
                btnco.setBounds(350,450,80,30);
                add(btnsa);
                add(btnco);
                btnsa.addActionListener(this);
                btnco.addActionListener(this);
                pid = new JTextField();
                pid.setBounds(270,50,180,30);
                name = new JTextField();
                name.setBounds(270,90,180,30);
                cno = new JTextField();
                cno.setBounds(270,130,180,30);
                age = new JTextField();
                age.setBounds(270,170,180,30);
                gen = new JComboBox<String>(new String[] {"Male","Female","Other"});
                gen.setBounds(270,210,180,30);
                bgrp = new JTextField();
                bgrp.setBounds(270,250,180,30);
                addr = new JTextField();
                addr.setBounds(270,290,180,30);
                anydis = new JTextField();
                anydis.setBounds(150,370,300,30);
                 add(pid);
                 add(name);
                 add(cno);
                 add(age);
                 add(gen);
                 add(bgrp);
                 add(addr);
                 add(anydis);
             //   Background image 
                img3 = new ImageIcon("image/m_back2.jpg");
                imglab3 = new JLabel(img3);
                imglab3.setSize(600,600);
                add(imglab3);
            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ael){
                    String str1 =ael.getActionCommand();
                    String PatientID =pid.getText();
                    String Pname =name.getText();
                    String ContactNumber =cno.getText();
                    String ages=age.getText();
                    String gender=(String)gen.getSelectedItem();
                    String bloodGroup=bgrp.getText();
                    String address=addr.getText();
                    String anyMajorDisease=anydis.getText(); 
                    if(str1.equals("Save")){
                    try {
                       String url="jdbc:ucanaccess://Hospital.accdb";
                       Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                       Statement st=connection.createStatement();
                       st.executeUpdate("insert into Patient(PatientID,Pname,ContactNumber,ages,gender,bloodGroup,address,anyMajorDisease) values('"+PatientID+"','"+Pname+"','"+ContactNumber+"','"+ages+"','"+gender+"','"+bloodGroup+"','"+address+"','"+anyMajorDisease+"')");
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Added New Patient Record Successfull");
                        }catch(Exception ex){
                                 ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
                    else if(str1.equals("Close")){
                       System.exit(0);     
                    }  
            }
    public static void main(String[] args){
         Anpr apr=new Anpr();
        apr.setVisible(true); 
     }
  }
```

Comment: Java naming conventions have classes start with an upper-case letter; methods and variables start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: You update the table, but I can imagine a successful update that is rolled back. I think it would be better if you used a prepared statement.

Comment: You should learn to use parameters with your statement, see [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for safer, more readable and in general better code. You also need to validate any mandatory values. Do you get an exception?

Comment: Ok now my data is inserting into my database but every time it automatically add #Delete like in above image row because of that it throws warning every time while i click on save button to backe detail in database

Answer (score 0):

#Deleted is a Microsoft Access application error message that can have many underlying causes. When all data is displayed as #deleted there's usually a problem with the primary key value that exceeds the range that MS Access supports.

Check all the values you insert into the table and make sure that they do not exceed maximum size of the specified data type (e.g. too many characters in case of VARCHAR, or a numeric value that is out of range). Also ensure that you do not use string values where numeric values are expected (the used JDBC driver may convert strings to unexpeced numeric values)